# Replacing specific characters in a string - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, replace

Okay, so I'm trying to create a JavaScript function to replace specific characters in a string. What I mean by this is, lets say, searching a string character by character for a letter and if it matches, replacing it with another character. Ex, replacing "a" with "x": `Hello, how are you?` becomes `Hello, how xre you?` and `Greetings and salutations` becomes `Greetings and sxlutations`.

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: `String.prototype.replace` does exactly this. ex: `('halp me plase').replace('a', 'x') === 'hxlp me plase'`

Comment: See http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp with javascript or http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2012/07/jquery-replace-strings.html with Jquery

Answer (score 2):

for removing multiple characters you could use a regex expression

```
yourString.replace(new RegExp('a', 'g'), 'x')
```

for removing the same with a case-insensitive match use

```
yourString.replace(new RegExp('a', 'gi'), 'x')
```

Answer (score 1):

As `String.replace()` does not seem to fullfil the OPs desires, here is a full function to do the stuff the OP asked for.

```
function rep(s,from,to){
  var out = "";
  // Most checks&balances ommited, here's one example
  if(to.length != 1 || from.length != 1)
    return NULL;

  for(var i = 0;i < s.length; i++){
    if(s.charAt(i) === from){
      out += to;
    } else {
      out += s.charAt(i);
    }
  }
  return out;
}

rep("qwertz","r","X")
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var s1 = document.getElementById('s1').innerHTML;
var s2 = s1.replace('a', 'x');
document.getElementById('s2').innerHTML = s2;
```

```html
<h1>Starting string:</h1>
<p id="s1">Hello, how are you?</p>

<h1>Resulting string:</h1>
<p id="s2"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple utility function that will replace all *old* characters in some string *str* with the *replacement* character/string.

```
    function replace(str, old, replacement) {
        var newStr = new String();
        var len = str.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if (str[i] == old)
                newStr = newStr.concat(replacement);
            else
                newStr = newStr.concat(str[i]);                  
        }
        return str;
    }
```